# C++ command line compiler for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio Express 2012 and I have added `cl.exe` to my PATH but apparently is missing a dll ( ? ), the `mspdb110.dll`, I have also noticed that there are 2 `cl.exe` in 2 different paths:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64
```

how i can compile a file `main.cpp` from the command line with the VS compiler ?
Where I can find a reference for this compiler ?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for doing it the right way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run the **vcvarsall.bat** batch file from the VC directory under whatever directory you installed Visual Studio to (e.g., on my PC, it's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC).  This batch file will configure the environment for toolchain use.

By default, it will configure the environment for use of the x86 native toolchain.  You can also provide an argument to the batch file to use a different toolchain.  For example, you can pass **amd64** to use the native x64 toolchain, or **x86_amd64** to use the x86 -> x64 cross compilation toolchain.  Take a look at the contents of the batch file if you are interested in other options or what, exactly, it configures.

Comment: thanks, i should start to power-off my brain before using Windows, ... I would be curious to know what is the point of doing a second setup after the first one and making things so complicated ... anyway, this works.

Comment: What are the first and second steps and which one is complicated?

Comment: I should indicate that vcvarsall.bat is the only good way to use it. I have 3 major visual studio versions(2008 for python,2010 for CUDA,2012 for common purpose) installed. Without vcvarsall.bat files, I were completely doomed because of configuration (PATH etc.) changes.

Comment: under linux you install a compiler/IDE, you get a working compiler, under Windows i have installed Visual Studio 2012 i didn't get a working compiler.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı i need to remove cl.exe from the PATH ?

Comment: @user1824407:  It's possible to install multiple versions of Visual C++.  The vcvarsall.bat batch file enables you to use different toolchains by configuring the environment specifically for each.  If everything was just added to %path%, that wouldn't work.  Even if you have only one version of Visual Studio installed, there are four different toolchains that get installed:  the x86 and x64 native toolchains and the x86 -> x64 and x86 -> arm cross compilation toolchains.  The environment needs to be configured for each of these.

Comment: @user1824407 IMO you should remove if you want to have a clean development environment. But it's not necessary if you will develop for only 1 architecture and if you don't have conflicting software needs like me. For your first comment, you get the compiler, yet it's not auto-configured for working system wide.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis makes sense but there is really no doc that tells you that this way ...